# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001C480BD0040> but Image.open can open images

Tags: python, image, keras, model

I have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "===", line 51, in 
history = model.fit(train_generator,
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2943, in open
raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001C480BD0040>
when I'm trying to train my keras model. I read in other questions that it can be caused by damaged images but when I use Image.open (as it was advised) with all of my images everything is fine and there is no error.

Code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,  MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense,Dropout
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

    Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),


    Flatten(),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    Dense(9, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')

])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])



TRAINING_DIR = "./train_faces_new"
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255,
                                   brightness_range=(0.1, 0.9),
                                   rotation_range=40,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
                                                    batch_size=15,
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))
VALIDATION_DIR = "./test"
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                         batch_size=10,
                                                         target_size=(150, 150))

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model2-{epoch:03d}.modelFACES33',monitor='val_loss',verbose=0,save_best_only=True,mode='auto')

history = model.fit(train_generator,
                              epochs=20,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Error shows up after 1st epoch

Epoch 1/20
266/266 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5636 - acc: 0.5148

I have no idea what's going on. Also I need to say that everything worked good but I lost all of my photos and code, then I restore it but I got all new photos so they are not damaged.
Thank you in advance for help.